# Elasticsearch high CPU load on bulk upserts

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch server gets a massive CPU spike every day, when tens if not hundreds of thousands of records get upserted in `bulk` requests (usually 500-1000 records per request). CPU gets basically locked at 100%, ES becomes unresponsive and eventually dies.

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-05-29 08:06:38 UTC; 23min ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 2437 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet -Edefault.path.logs=${LOG
  Process: 2433 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2437 (code=exited, status=127)

May 29 08:06:38 elastic1 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
May 29 08:06:38 elastic1 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 29 08:06:38 elastic1 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Here's an overview of some of the indices: [image: indices]
Encircled ones are some of the ones that are being updated during this time, and they all have a proportionally large amount of `docs.deleted`, which might have something to do with this...?

ES 5.3.2, single EC2 t2.small instance type, single core, 2gb RAM + 2gb swap, 30gb SSD.

Is there anything anyone can suggest to debug / fix the high CPU load? Hopefully there's something that can be done, outside of just increasing the EC2 instance size.

Limiting throughput of those bulk requests may be something I can try, but, again, hopefully it can be fixed without that.

Perhaps two shards per indices of those sizes are too much?

I'm going to try to provide `_nodes/hot_threads` output during the next spike.

EDIT 1:
Here's CloudWatch monitoring over 12h period. Usually CPU usage is well below 50% even when spiking during bulk updates, busy search hours, etc. Normal usage is closer to 5%.
[image: cpu usage overview]

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt this is going to help anyone else, but after rebooting my ec2 instance it seems that the spikes have decreased significantly, never exceeding 30% now. That instance was running uninterrupted for almost a year, I think.